# Pre-coding documents for naive-bayes

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am working on an automatic content analysis. The measurement will have six dimensions and the scale of measurement will be metric with three levels. The dataset contains 4000 cases.

Example:
- Dimension 1: 1 = positive, 0 = neutral, -1 = negative , NA = not 
   available 
- Dimension 2: 1 = positive, 0 = neutral, -1 = negative,  NA = not
   available 
- etc.

The content analyses will be executed through a naive-bayes algorithm with the tm-package in R. To do this, I have to train the algorithm first. This means I have to code some documents manualy so that the algorithm can "learn" the coding rules. 
Therefore, I have to develop a train and a test set with pre-coded documents. The goal is, that algorithm is right in 80% of the cases. 
My question is, how many documents I have to code manually to reach this goal? For example, assumed I would code 300 documents manually and make a train-test-set where I put 100 documents in the train-set and 200 documents in the test-set.  The result would be that the algorithm is right in only 30% of the cases. So I would have to execute the manual coding process again. Is there a rule have many documents I have to code manualy? Thanks.